# ALDialog not working after special start-up

Tags: nao-robot, choregraphe

I accidentally did a special start-up by pressing the chest button a little too long and after that ALDialog is no longer functioning. This happened on Sunday 2024-02-04.

Two errors seem to occur. One regarding behavior.box and one regarding ALDialog. The first one occurs immediately when starting the robot and the second one when trying to use dialog.

We have tried almost everyting at this point. Reinstalling Choregraphe, factory resetting the robot. Updated all the softwares in the robot settings application.

We tried doing this very basic example: https://support.aldebaran.com/support/solutions/articles/80001016926-tutorial-creating-dialog-boxes and it still gives the same error.

In the picture I'm attaching you can see that we have tried using Swedish, but the same thing occurs with English. The dialog box simply won't work. Do you have any ideas what the problem can be?

We have tried almost everyting at this point. Reinstalling Choregraphe, factory resetting the robot. Updated all the softwares in the robot settings application.

We tried doing this very basic example: https://support.aldebaran.com/support/solutions/articles/80001016926-tutorial-creating-dialog-boxes and it still gives the same error.

In the picture I'm attaching you can see that we have tried using Swedish, but the same thing occurs with English. The dialog box simply won't work. Do you have any ideas what the problem can be?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.